# Does class autoloading not work in standalone phpunit testing?

Tags: civix, unit-testing, phpunit, autoloading

I'm following [civix's upgrade instructions](https://github.com/totten/civix/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#upgrade-test-files) to enable unit tests to be executed with standalone phpunit.

I've got my code in a [work-in-progress git branch](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/415/commits). The first commit captures the civix-generated boilerplate phpunit.xml.dist and bootstrap.php. The second commit captures my attempts to adapt an existing test to the new way of doing things.

With these changes in place, I do:

```
$ cd /path/to/webroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/tools/extensions/civivolunteer
$ phpunit4 tests/phpunit/api/v3/VolunteerProjectTest.php
```

... and get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'VolunteerTestAbstract' not found in /path/to/webroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/tools/extensions/civivolunteer/tests/phpunit/api/v3/VolunteerProjectTest.php on line 6
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/lib/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpunit4:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/lib/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpunit4:545
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///usr/local/lib/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpunit4/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:100
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() phar:///usr/local/lib/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpunit4/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:123
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() phar:///usr/local/lib/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpunit4/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:67
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() phar:///usr/local/lib/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpunit4/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:123
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() phar:///usr/local/lib/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpunit4/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:39
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() phar:///usr/local/lib/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpunit4/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php:38
PHP   9. include_once() phar:///usr/local/lib/civicrm-buildkit/bin/phpunit4/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php:56
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Civi's autoloader does not load classes outside the CRM directory. In order for that to work, you'll have a few options:

- Implement your own autoloader capable of loading classes inside the test/phpunit dir
- Use require to include the class
- Put the VolunteerTestAbstract class inside your CRM dir

I usually use the second option for that and include/require the class(es) on the bootstrap.php file.

I also like the third option. For that, you would put the class somewhere like CRM_Volunteer_Test_VolunteerTestAbstract and then just extend it. No need for requires or to implement your own autoloader.

Comment: Thanks, Davi. Have called it a day but will have another look over the weekend.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with intermediate base-classes for tests (like `VolunteerTestAbstract`). The most reliable solution I've found is to put a `require_once` to load the intermediate base-class. For example, this is what I used in [`uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico`](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/blob/e52e7f4753888c8df4a9d27810219fb2700b1279/tests/phpunit/CRM/Mosaico/MosaicoTemplateTest.php):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/TestCase.php';

class CRM_Mosaico_MosaicoTemplateTest extends CRM_Mosaico_TestCase implements EndToEndInterface {
     ...
}
```

Unfortunately, it's hard to combine PHPUnit with a classloader that understands extensions. To see why, consider an example command:

```
phpunit4 tests/phpunit/CRM/Mosaico/MosaicoTemplateTest.php
```

Which would then:

- A. Load test files, e.g.

  1. Load `tests/phpunit/bootstrap.php`
  2. Load `tests/phpunit/CRM/Mosaico/MosaicoTemplateTest.php` (which depends on a base class like `CRM_Mosaico_TestCase`)
  3. Load `tests/phpunit/CRM/Mosaico/TestCase.php`
- B. Begin executing the test logic, e.g.

  1. Execute `CiviTestListener`
  2. Execute `setupBeforeClass()`
  3. Execute `setUp()`

The problem arises if the database-initialization (eg `\Civi\Test::headless()->installMe(__DIR__)->apply()`) is put in phase B test-logic (e.g. `CiviTestListener` or `setupBeforeClass()` or `setUp()`) . The database-initialization determines which extensions are active. The active extensions determine the class-loader. But all of this comes too late. During steps A2=>A3 (when we need autoloading), the extension-enabled class-loader isn't available yet.

Put another way: any code which references an autoloaded extension class has an implicit dependency on the database.

One can resolve this conundrum a couple ways, e.g.

- In `tests/phpunit/bootstrap.php`, fully initialize the system. (Ex: In the line `eval(cv('php:boot --level=classloader', 'phpcode'));`, change the `--level` to `settings` or `full`.) This makes sense if all the tests are end-to-end (`e2e`).
- Load classes in a way which does not implicitly depend on the database. The simplest thing is to do a `require_once` to load the target class. (EDIT: What's a nice place to put the `require_once` statement? I originally put it in each test class, but on second thought... it would be more elegant to put it in `tests/phpunit/boostrap.php`.)

(I'm writing this to help me get the problem a bit clearer in mind... hopefully that will eventually lead to a better solution...)