# class Civi not found

Tags: civicrm-buildkit, unit-testing, phpunit, autoloading

I'm trying to use the `Civi` class to debug an extension with build kit,
but after I add this line:

```
   `Civi::log()->info('Hello, log!');`
```

to my class I get:

`ampuser@58e3a823b9ee:/opt/buildkit/build/dmaster/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/api4$ phpunit4
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Civi\API\V4\Civi' not found in /opt/buildkit/build/dmaster/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/api4/Civi/API/V4/Action.php on line 117`

I feel like this ought to work out of the box... am I doing something wrong?

This feels like a variant of [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16418/class-naming-and-namespaces-best-practice-as-an-extension-author) and [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15810/does-class-autoloading-not-work-in-standalone-phpunit-testing) question ... but different in that I'm looking for the pattern to call a core class

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it turns out I was kinda doing something wrong...

What I needed was a simple **`\`** prefix:

`\Civi::log()->info('Hello, log!');`

Comment: The CRM* classes also seem to need a leading "\" too